# Division by zero, modify function

Tags: php, function

Hi I have a small problem, namely - I wrote the overhead calculation function, based on input data (net price, sales price and VAT). Unfortunately - the program works fine until it goes to undefined values, so I get zero errors. How can I modify this function so that when echaing echo is displayed instead of giving the actual result?

```
function getMarkup($netprice, $fullprice, $vat) {
    $markup = 100 * (($fullprice / ($netprice * (1 + $vat / 100)) - 1));
    return round(100 * $markup) / 100;
}
```

Comment: Give us an example of one such undefined error

Comment: you get zero errors? or you get errors?

Comment: You can store this `$netprice * (1 + $vat / 100)) - 1)` in a variable and test if it's greater then 0 before you do the division!

Comment: I get errors for division by zero https://3v4l.org/LXHDP maybe you have errors off?

Comment: You'll get division by zero errors if netprice is zero, so simply test for that before doing the math

Comment: Also if `$vat == -100` you'll get division by 0 error

Comment: I'd have thought it was better to trap any conditions where you don't have a net price (for example) before calling a function to calculate the markup.

Comment: You could replace `round(100 * $markup) / 100;` by `round($markup,2);`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your passed in values are set to a number larger than 0. Throw an InvalidArgumentException if they pass in rubbish.

```
function getMarkup($netprice, $fullprice, $vat) {

    if (!$netprice > 0 || !$fullprice > 0 || !$vat > 0) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('please pass valid numbers');
    }

    $markup = 100 * (($fullprice / ($netprice * (1 + $vat / 100)) - 1));
    return round(100 * $markup) / 100;
}
```